# REST API access_token is invalid

Tags: rest-api, api, rest, invalid

Making  a small application in PHP for a project, I have to ask users to authenticate to the application using their SalesForce account.

I redirect them to the login page, with the correct client_id, and the callback is well triggered. I get the code, and do an API call to get the access_code.

At first run, it works well, the user gets prompted to log in, and the token request provides me a valid access_code; But after a few hours, If the user reconnects using the button "log in with SalesForce", it gets me the same access_token as before, which is now invalid, triggering the following error while trying to access any API data:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Session expired or invalid",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
  }
]
```

The token requests outputs me something like that:

```
{
    "access_token": "00D0Y00...!ARU...PL03x",
    "signature": "aQuiteWellEncodedString=",
    "scope": "full",
    "id_token": "very-long-id-token",
    "instance_url": "https://eu11.salesforce.com",
    "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D0Y000something/0050Y0000something",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "issued_at": "1481640159252"
}
```

The thing is, the connected app is set as 30m Session expiry, yet the token sent after even 2 or 3 hours is still the same;

Where when I use a new access_token (another connected app freshly made) the same request (except for the Authorization header to suit the new one), it works just well.

The connected app is set to **Full Access**, and the dummy call is sent as a **GET**, to

```
https://eu11.salesforce.com/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account/describe
```

The calls have been tested from cURL request, Postman (Chrome extension) and directly from Application code, with the same result.

Comment: Can you provide params you using in Postman or Curl which we can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to refresh the token since the token does have an expiration. I think 120 min.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm

I'm new to Salesforce but had just used Postman to test a connected app also. Kept getting this same error until I request a new token and pass that in the new post.

Comment: I tried to add the refresh_token scope, but any request will give me the same token as yesterday (13rd december) with previous scope (full only, not refresh_token or offline_access). Even the issued_at epoch time is at 13rd dec. Thus I don't even have the refresh_token in the server response token call, as displayed in sample data of my original post

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting proper header while making the 2nd call?

```
curl https://eu11.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Account/describe/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00D50000000IehZ\!AQcAQH0dMHZfz972Szmpkb58urFRkgeBGsxL_QJWwYMfAbUeeG7c1E6LYUfiDUkWe6H34r1AAwOR8B8fLEz6n04NPGRrq0FM'
```

try replacing with your session id/accesstoken you got after authentication.